# react-boilerplate i18n change locale

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl, react-boilerplate

hi i'm new to react and now i developed front end using react-boilerplate.. 
i'm trying to add new language to my application. 
i follow this documentation : [i18n docs](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/js/i18n.md)
to generate (add) new language and extract all language..

but now i'm confused how i can test if it's work or not.. i can change DEFAULT_LOCALE (\app\containers\App\constants.js) value to the language specifier i want to test, and it will worked. 
but i'm expecting to test it by setting up locale in client and then the react-boilerplate will detect which locale should it display.

question :

1. how this react-boilerplate detect locale ? from browser accepted language / browser language / client OS language ?
2. how can i change react-boilerplate locale on the fly ?

Please throw some enlightment.. many thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2):

You can get the browser's language using the code below. Note that this method will return the user's "preferred language" in Chrome not Chrome's display language. It is still mostly accurate.

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

In `containers/LanguageProvider/actions.js` you can dispatch the provided `changeLocale` action creator anywhere in the application to change the language on the fly.

As for setting the detected locale as default you can modify the `LanguageProvider` container as follows:

```
...other imports
import {changeLocale} from './actions';

export class LanguageProvider extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.changeLocale(navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);

  }
  // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {
    return (
      <IntlProvider
        locale={this.props.locale}
        key={this.props.locale}
        messages={this.props.messages[this.props.locale]}
      >
        {React.Children.only(this.props.children)}
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
}

LanguageProvider.propTypes = {
  locale: PropTypes.string,
  messages: PropTypes.object,
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(makeSelectLocale(), locale => ({
  locale,
}));

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeLocale: (lang) => dispatch(changeLocale(lang)),
  };
}
... other code
```

Note that this will set the locale to the format of `en-US` in case of US language, so you must either reformat the string or change the name of the language file in the translations folder.
Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: That helped thank you.

You can add that line to propTypes: 

`changeLocale: PropTypes.func.isRequired,`

Answer (score 0):

Here are my answers to your question.

1) It depends on the browser default language.

2) I think there is not a special method. Try to select a language on your preference.

Comment: hi Hiroto, thanks for your prompt response.. be default my chrome browser language is english, i have add new language by generate it using CLI. I add Indonesia. I add the translations for Indonesia language. Then i change my browser default language to Indonesia and relaunch the browser. Still the displayed language in my react apps is in English. Correct result will show if i change / hardcode the DEFAULT_LOCALE to "id" (without quote).

Answer (score 0):

i replicate the react-boilerplate change locale feature, just recognized that the demo version is already include that feature. it didn't check browser or client os language for i know, but it using DEFAULT_LOCALE settings for default display language.